# MAD & Median of weighted GMM

Tags: normal-distribution, gaussian-mixture-distribution, order-statistics, scipy, mad

What is the median and median-absolute-deviation of a weighted GMM in terms of component mean and variance? For example, three normal distributions $A$, $B$, $C$ with means $\mu_a,\mu_b,\mu_c$, variances $\sigma^2_a,\sigma^2_b,\sigma^2_c$ and weights $p_a,p_b,p_c$ where $p_a+p_b+p_c = 1$.

*Since neither median nor MAD are moments, I believe you can't use any of the laws of total moments. Do you have to sum the component PDFs, integrate to CDF, take the inverse...*

Comment: The median is the weighted sum of CDFs set to $\frac{1}{2}$ which is equivalent to a sum of $erf$ and can be solved numerically if all the constants are known. The mad is piecewise the weighted sum of CDFs when $x-median > 0$, the weighted sum of negative CDFs otherwise, set to $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Yes, you have to sum the pdfs and take the inverse of the cdf. Even for an equal mixture of $N(0,1)$ and $N(2,3)$, there is no nice expression for the median.